# Find daily backup sizes in DPM 2007

Tags: synchronization, scdpm

I'm considering setting up a DPM server offsite and synchronising it with my onsite DPM server. How can I determine the size of the changes that would be replicated (based on my historical data) so that I can determine if we have the bandwidth to support this?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31267794/bandwidth-requirements-fo.aspx

Ah, my google-fu caught up. 512kbps is recommended so if I get a 1 megabit sdsl line I should be OK...

P